# What is the purpose of array.entries() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator

I'm having trouble understanding why array.entries exists if arrays themselves are iterables?

If I can use a iterable consumer with a simple array (e.g., [1, 2, 3]) then why would it be required to convert an array to an array iterator?

I can't think of any examples where this function would be useful in the real world. Please could someone provide an example of where array.entries() might be used and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method [Array.prototype.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) allows you to use an Iterator object, like you already pointed out correctly.

The major aspect is that you can use e.g. the [`.next()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/next) method. You can read more about iterators and iterables in the [MDN JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators). This is especially useful if you want to **cycle through an array without using a loop**.

It also opens you the possibility to make an **infinite iterator** like this:

```
var ids = {
  *[Symbol.iterator]: function () {
    var index = 0;

    return {
      next: function () {
        return { value: 'id-' + index++, done: false };
      }
    };
  }
};

var counter = 0;

for (var value of ids) {
  console.log(value);

  if (counter++ > 1000) { // let's make sure we get out!
    break;
  }
}
```

[Source](https://developer.ibm.com/node/2015/07/16/introduction-to-es6-iterators/)

Answer (score 3):

The most important aspect of using an iterator object is that you have more control over the looping of the iterator object.

Example
You have an array

```
let userName = ["John", "Sam", "Michael"];
```

You wanted to show the user only the first userName at the start (John), but after that, you provide functionality where the user would click on the button which shows the next username(Sam).

So if it is an iterator object you have **.next()** method, which can be called on each user click and provide a value next in the interation, since it would remember the previous pointer.

```
let iteratorUserName = userName.entries();
```

Button where the user would click

```
button.onclick = () => {
  let nextUserName = iteratorUserName.next();
  if(!nextUserName.done) {
    return nextUserName.value;
  } else {
      alert("No User");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
var iter = [].entries.call("stackoverflow")
iter.next();  // { value: [0, "s"], done: false }
iter.next();  // { value: [1, "t"], done: false }
...
```

Works for any array-like object, e.g. strings, and node lists. It is maybe not the most important function there is, but it does not hurt to have it.

Comment: In that case i would prefer Array.from("abc").entries() as being more readable...

Answer (score 0):

I like

```
for(const [i,v] of [1,2,3].entries()) alert(i,v);
```